# Spark loading a large parquet file long Garbage Collection Times

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have large table saved as a parquet and when I try to load it I get an crazy amount of `GC-Time` like 80%. I use spark 2.4.3 The parquet is saved with the following schema:

```
/parentfolder/part_0001/parquet.file
/parentfolder/part_0002/parquet.file
/parentfolder/part_0003/parquet.file
                [...]
2432 in total
```

The table in total is `2.6 TiB` and looks like this (both fields are 64bit int's):

```
+-----------+------------+
|        a  |         b  |
+-----------+------------+
|85899366440|515396105374|
|85899374731|463856482626|
|85899353599|661424977446|

          [...]
```

I have a total amount of `7.4 TiB` cluster memory, with 480 cores, on 10 workers and I read the parquet like this:

```
df = spark.read.parquet('/main/parentfolder/*/').cache()
```

and as I said I get an crazy amount of garbage collection time right now it stands at: `Task Time (GC Time) | 116.9 h (104.8 h)` with only `110 GiB` loaded after 22 min of wall time.
I monitor one of the `workers` and memory usual hover around 546G/748G

what am I doing wrong here? Do I need a larger cluster? If my Dataset is `2.6 TiB` why isn't `7.4 TiB` of memory enough? But then again why isn't the memory full on my worker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Garbage collection time very high in spark application causing program halt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589051/garbage-collection-time-very-high-in-spark-application-causing-program-halt)

Comment: provide your driver and executor memory in spark-submit here. i think you are using default (`bin/spark-submit` will also read configuration options from `conf/spark-defaults.conf` ) thats the reason it is cribbing.

Comment: hey good guess but no im not using the default. I set the values right in the app with: `.set('spark.executor.memory','740g').set('spark.driver.memory','740g')`

Answer (score 1):

just try to remove `.cache()`.
There are only few cases where you need to cache your data, the most obvious one is **one dataframe, several actions**. But if your dataframe is that big, do not use `cache`. Use `persist`.

```py
from pyspark import StorageLevel
df = spark.read.parquet('/main/parentfolder/*/').persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```

Comment: I will try this as well, but the problem is after I load the `dataframe` I do several action on it. It's turned into a graphframe and pageranked which itterates about 50 times on the `dataframe`

Comment: @Thagor That is why `persist` on disk is the good solution for your problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

see Databrics article on this...

### [Tuning Java Garbage Collection for Apache Spark Applications](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/05/28/tuning-java-garbage-collection-for-spark-applications.html)

G1 GC Running Status (after Tuning)

```
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -Xms88g -Xmx88g -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:ConcGCThread=20
```

need to garbge collector tuning in this case. try above example conf.

- Also make sure that in your submit you are passing right parameters like executor memory driver memory

use

[`scala.collection.Map<String,scala.Tuple2<Object,Object>>  getExecutorMemoryStatus()`
***Return a map from the slave to the max memory available for caching and the remaining memory available for caching.***](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#getExecutorMemoryStatus--)

call and debug using
`getExecutorMemoryStatus` API using pyspark's py4j bridge

```
sc._jsc.sc().getExecutorMemoryStatus()
```

Comment: Hey I will look into the garbage collection! I'm pretty sure master and worker memory is set correctly I do the "in app' with, `.set('spark.executor.memory','740g').set('spark.driver.memory','740g')` . Can I pass the aboive config with `.set('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions','-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal [...]')` ?